# Pandas `replace` * in signature

Tags: pandas, dataframe, documentation

Following is the signature for the `replace` method in Pandas API (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

```
DataFrame.replace(to_replace=None, value=_NoDefault.no_default, *, 
     inplace=False, limit=None, regex=False, method=_NoDefault.no_default)
```

While I understand the API method, I do not understand what does that `*` refer to in the arguments string. My guess would be that it is something related to `*args`. Perhaps `*`-like notation can be used after the second argument, but I wanted some clarity on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to make all arguments after it keyword only. The `*` catches the third and more unnamed parameters.

Thus in this method, only `to_replace` and `value` can be passed directly:

```
df.replace('a', 'b')
```

[pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) had been transitioning from classical ordered parameter to keyword-only for many methods lately. This improves on usability/readability for many cases. For instance `pivot`/`pivot_table` have so far similar parameters but in a different order, which makes it difficult to remember. In the future, enforcing keyword-only will make it unambiguous.

Comment: I see, thanks! Is this some standard notation, the star delimiter, I haven't seen it anywhere

Comment: This is defined in [PEP3102](https://peps.python.org/pep-3102/)

Comment: Oh wow, I did not know this was pythonic! Haven't encountered them before. Thanks alot!